# Trying to create a carousel with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, carousel

I have an ng-repeat that displays images and their corresponding names in it's own DIV.

I would like to change this into a carousel where 3 of them show on screen and have a slider to move on to the next 3. I've succeeded in getting the names to display, albeit one at a time as opposed to the three i wanted, but images are a no show. Can anyone direct me to where I can look to make this work?

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">   
          <h4>Tailor the Message for Your Audience:</h4>
          <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel" id="slider" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="a in initiatives.audiences | orderBy:'position'" class="item" ng-if="a.name !== $parent.$state.params.audience_name && a.name !== 'core-message'">
                <a href="{{ a.name }}" force-refresh>
                    <!-- <div class="rectangle"> -->
                    <img ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + a.hero + ')'}"></img>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                    <p>{{ a.name.replace('-', ' ') }}</p>         
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#slider" data-slide="next"></a>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting the `<img>` element?

Comment: Yeah, it should be ng-src within the `img` tag and not ng-style with a background image.

Comment: ng-src worked to get the image to show. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
<img ng-src="{{ a.hero }}"></img>
```